# Can resizing dynamic array of reference-counted interfaces with SetLength() cause memory leak?

Tags: pascal, freepascal, delphi

If I have following type declaration of a reference-counted interface.

```
type
    ISomeInterface = interface
       ['{xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxx}']
       procedure doThing();
    end;

    TSomeInterfaceImpl = class(TInterfacedObject, ISomeInterface)
    public
       procedure doThing();
    end; 
...
var arrayOfSomeInterface : array of ISomeInterface;
```

Will following code cause memory leak?

```
SetLength(arrayOfSomeInterface, 1);
arrayOfSomeInterface[0] := TSomeInterfaceImpl.create();
SetLength(arrayOfSomeInterface, 2);
arrayOfSomeInterface[1] := TSomeInterfaceImpl.create();
```

From what I know, when SetLength() is called on dynamic array, it will allocate new memory for new dynamic array and then copy old array content to new array.

What happened to reference count of interface in old array. Will it be properly decremented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no leak.

The memory manager will try to expand the existing memory block in-place. If it can, no references are affected. But, if it can't, it will copy the array to a new memory block. The resulting interface references will have the same reference counts they had before the copy. Increasing the size of an array does not add or remove references of existing array elements, only moves them from one memory location to another. This is perfectly safe.

Interfaces and dynamic arrays are both managed types, the compiler and RTL will manage them correctly.